# Basic Blazor Component property rendering issue

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am finding myself repeating a lot of code when writing Blazor, so decided to start making components.  However I can't get some basics working with showing the properties of the Child with the first render of the Parent page.

Simplified to show the issue:

**Child Component**

```
<div class="col-2"> <input @bind="TotalRows"></input> Total Rows</div>
<div class="col-2"> @TotalRows Total Rows</div>
<div class="col-2"> @GetRows() Total Rows</div>

@code {
    public DataTable dtFull = new DataTable();        
    public int TotalRows { get; set; } = 0;   

    public RBTest() { }

    public RBTest(RBDataTable i_RBDT)
    {        
        dtFull = i_RBDT.ReadAllDetails(); //This is just a Data Access Layer
        TotalRows = dtFull.Rows.Count;
    }

    public int GetRows()
    {
        return TotalRows;
    }    
}
```

**Parent Page**

```
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<RBTest @ref="Test"></RBTest>
<div>@Test.GetRows()</div>

@code 
{
    RBTest Test = new RBTest(); //Blazor Component
    T_DIV_DIVIDEND Data = new T_DIV_DIVIDEND(); //DAL ignore for now.

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Test  = new RBTest(Data.RBDT);        
    }
}
```

**Results**

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKpqr.png)

Everything in the Child Component is being set correctly, TotalRows has the correct value, but at the time of rendering the Parent, TotalRows is showing 0.

I assume its a timing/rendering concept that I am not getting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a [mre] that doesn't have stuff like `dtFull = i_RBDT.ReadAllDetails();` which means absolutely nothing to anyone other that you.  "I assume its a timing/rendering concept that I am not getting". Correct but without some [mre] code as common ground it's difficult to demonstrate were your problems are.

Comment: See my answer where I've taken a shot at the [mre] and an answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Don't `new()` your Blazor components. They won't render.

> Everything in the Child Component is being set correctly

In the copy that you created, yes. But the Parent will create another one and use the `public RBTest() { }` constructor.

Add `[Parameter] RBDataTable RBDT : get; set; }` to the child.

And use it in the Parent like this

```
<RBTest RBDT="Data.RBDT"></RBTest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I can't initiate the Child Component or pass anything to it, in the Code part of the parent.  I have to do it in the HTML.  The problem is that the Data object is null at that point.

Comment: It will become non-null and hen rendered again. I did indeed leave out all null handling.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the provided code correctly, you need to separate your data [and it's state] from your components.

Here's my *Minimal Reproducible Example* of your code, using the `WeatherForecastService` to provide some data, that demonstrates using a cascaded service to hold the data state.

First a simple DataState Service.

```
public class TestStateData
{
    private WeatherForecastService _weatherForecastService;
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Items { get; private set; } = Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();
    public Task LoadingTask { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;

    public TestStateData(WeatherForecastService service)
    {
        _weatherForecastService = service;
        // as ctor's cannot be async we kick off the data get and assign the retuened Task to a property extenbral processes can check
        this.LoadingTask = LoadItemsAsync();
    }

    public int GetRows()
        => Items.Count();

    private async Task LoadItemsAsync()
        => this.Items = await _weatherForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now));
}
```

And register it as a Transient:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<TestStateData>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Your component.

We capture a cascaded instance of `TestStateData` and use it.

```cs
<div class="col-2 mb-2"> <input @bind="TotalRows"></input> Total Rows</div>
<div class="col-2 mb-2"> @TotalRows Total Rows</div>
<div class="col-2 mb-2"> @_testStateData.GetRows() Total Rows</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private TestStateData _testStateData { get; set; } = default!;

    private int TotalRows; 

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // throw an exception is we haven't set up the cascade at design time
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(_testStateData);
        // await the loading process
        await _testStateData.LoadingTask;

        TotalRows = _testStateData.GetRows();
    }
}
```

And the demo page.

We get the instance of `TestStateData` and cascade it to the sub-components.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject TestStateData StateData

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<CascadingValue Value="this.StateData" IsFixed>
    <RBTest />
</CascadingValue>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Row Count: @this.StateData.GetRows()</pre>
    </div>

@code
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        => await this.StateData.LoadingTask;
}
```

We don't use a `Scoped` service as this would not match the scope of the component.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, kind of you to provide some examples.

Clearly I need to do some more basic reading, as I don't understand many of the concepts you have mentioned (such as Services, Cascading Values) and why you would choose those options.

Comment: First steps.  There's plenty of tutorials out there to get you up and running.

Answer (score -2):

I found two solutions in the end.

Using the Constructor is a no-no for some reason.  So I can just move the logic to a method passing the Data.RBDT and then it works.  I didn't need to use a [Parameter]

**Parent**

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    Test.SetVals(Data.RBDT);               
}
```

**Child**

```
public void SetVals(RBDataTable i_RBDT)
{
    RBDT = i_RBDT;
    dtFull = RBDT.ReadAll();
    TotalRows = dtFull.Rows.Count;
    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

Second is using a [Parameter] in the Child, add code to ignore Nulls and then again using the above to call a Method to set the properties without passing the Data.RBDT in the method.

I have no idea what is best practice or if I should be using a completely different approach, but at least it works now.

Comment: This is definitely not the answer to the issue.  It may "work" in this instance, but if you start using this pattern you will quickly get yourself into all sorts of knots, and start plastering `this.StateHasChanged();` all over your code to try and keep things in sync.  See my comment on your question about producing a [mre].